# MySQL - Should I create new table in mysql for member profile?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Should I create new table for member's profile?
I have already table that has Username, password and Email  for register and login.
but after login, I will redirect the user to editprofile page that have firstname, lastname, gender, phone, address. 
or should I use all column in 1 table database for member

Comment: If you want to keep those login informations in separate secure database it is better to keep them in separate tables else just go with single table as long as its not violating normalizations rules

Comment: I do not agree. You have a 1,1 relationship, so in order to follow such as MERISE rules, you definitely want to have a single table with all informations. It's more performant (no need to do a join to get data from both tables).

Comment: If you have already saved the information in that table while register, you can use that table.

Comment: Show us your current design, and the two possible new designs.